# Using Stack Overflow to learn a programming language

Tags: discussion

Learning a programming language may sometime require extensive understanding of the various paradigms and theories, but for a newbie a single book or documentation is so overwhelming that it is easy to be lost.

But a site like Stack Overflow, so abundant with expert users.. yet people (like me) easily get downvoted for asking broad questions. Well, it is from the broad questions and the answers likewise that we get some sort of checklist which can be used to learn a particular concept.

Is there any way that Stack Overflow can be lenient in this regard? After all, not everyone at anytime can go to a school or shell out that five-figure fee to be able to learn.

Comment: Not really. There are plenty of free tutorials "out there" for any programming language you can think of. A lot of questions that are closed as "too bread" can be solved by simply searching for the issue on google.

Comment: If you're setting out to learn a new language, and you're overwhelmed by a single book, then may I suggest you try another book, preferably one that is targeted at newcomers to that language (or to programming in general)?

Comment: Understand that learning a language takes **a long time**. If you are overwhelmed by programming books, chances are you are trying to learn too fast.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the right site for these types of questions. Learning from books, make sure that you use **good** books. Particularly with technologies that become very popular, everybody and their dog writes a book about it. Many of them are poorly written. Look for reviews, and make sure that you get high quality books that are targeting your experience level. Explaining complex technical topics in understandable language, while still keeping everything correct and precise, takes a lot of skill. The best technical authors excel at it. Online resources are even more spotty.

Comment: Thank you everyone. I une understand the value of Good books and that SO cannot be treated as an instructor. The point I tried to make was even with the good books you might end up not able to understand some concepts and and will have to turn to the experts, and since the understanding was not there the question might end up being broad. SO is not for that but SO  hosts the people who can help you

Comment: -1: that means increased low quality faq-style questions

Comment: You shouldn't need to go to school to learn a programming language. There are a ton of tutorials online on every subject, and if you take the time to learn how to research correctly and break up your own problems you will not end up asking broad questions because you'll find that basically every "beginner" question has been asked here before (probably multiple times).

Answer (score 18):

The problem with 'too broad' questions is that they tend to get a book-style answer. That is exactly the kind of answer that SE wants to avoid.

Learning something takes a book, or a good set of tutorials. SE sites, and Stack Overflow in particular, aren't that. They are a knowledge base of to-the-point questions *and* answers.